# How to get Facebook first and last name values using ASP.NET MVC 5 and OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I know that a 'Name' field is provided, but I would prefer to access the first and last names explicitly. Can someone help with this? I'm still wrapping my head around ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your Startup.Auth.cs `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` method, set the following for Facebook:

```
var x = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        x.Scope.Add("email");
        x.AppId = "*";
        x.AppSecret = "**";
        x.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    foreach (var claim in context.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                        string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                        if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));

                    }

                }
        };

        x.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(x);
        /*
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: "*",
           appSecret: "*");
         * */
```

Then use this to access the user's login info:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

And then the following to get the first name:

```
var firstNameClaim = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:first_name");
```

Comment: Worked for me - then there's still the work of getting the value out provider-agnostic, which I'm currently doing like `public string FirstName { get { return chainValue( "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", // Google  "urn:facebook:first_name" // Facebook ); } }`

Answer (score 7):

Facebook changed its permission api. You can get more information about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Name need public_profile permission

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "appId",
    AppSecret = "key"
};
facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

And you can get it using:

```
var loginInfo = await authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:name")
```

authenticationManager is an instance, you can get using:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

Comment: Hi, where the loginInfo comes from? where should we place this line of code?

Comment: Hi, I edited answer, let me know, if anything is still missing. Take care!

Comment: This works for me; I can get the firstname + lastname. But email is always`null`. Also, do you know a way to get the first name and last name separately?

Comment: for me, name, first_name and last_name is `null`.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this method doesn't work anymore since Facebook changed their default return values with API update 2.4

It looks like the only way to get the first_name etc. now is to use the Facebook Graph API ([like this posts suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714500/access-email-address-in-the-oauth-externallogincallback-from-facebook-v2-4-api-i?lq=1)).

I also found [this post](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/417) on the Katana project site that addresses this issue and already submitted a pull request but it has not been merged jet.

Hopefully this safes somebody a little bit of time ;)

Answer (score 5):

As of 2017, this is the code that is working for me(Thanks to David Poxon's code above). Make sure you have upgraded to version 3.1.0 of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook`.

In the Startup.Auth.cs (or Startup.cs in some cases), place this code:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "***",
    AppSecret = "****",
    BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler(),
    UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name",
    Scope = { "email" },
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            foreach (var claim in context.User)
            {
                var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your controller's external login callback method, add this code:

```
var firstName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:first_name").Value;
```

Likewise for getting last name, use the above line and replace the `urn:facebook:first_name` with `urn:facebook:last_name`

Answer (score 1):

```
 private Uri RedirectUri
        {
            get
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
                uriBuilder.Query = null;
                uriBuilder.Fragment = null;
                uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");
                return uriBuilder.Uri;
            }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Facebook()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = "296002327404***",
            client_secret = "4614cd636ed2029436f75c77961a8***",
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            response_type = "code",
            scope = "email" // Add other permissions as needed
        });

        return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return View("Login");
    }
    public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "296002327404***",
            client_secret = "4614cd636ed2029436f75c77961a8***",
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            code = code
        });

        var accessToken = result.access_token;

        // Store the access token in the session for farther use
        Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

        // update the facebook client with the access token so 
        // we can make requests on behalf of the user
        fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

        // Get the user's information
        dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,middle_name,last_name,id,email");
        string email = me.email;
        string firstname = me.first_name;
        string middlename = me.middle_name;
        string lastname = me.last_name;

        db.Insert_customer(firstname,email,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,1,System.DateTime.Now,1,System.DateTime.Now);

        // Set the auth cookie
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Jan 2019, I wanted to confirm how to do this and provide a few extra bits (there is a lot of conflicting info out there depending on what year the answer was written!).  David and Waqas have the best answers (IMO).  I'm using MVC5, AspNetIdentity 2 and IdentityServer 3.

First, your identity provider configuration for Facebook:

```
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "facebook",
            Caption = "Login with Facebook",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

            AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
            AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],

            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = ctx =>
                {
                    foreach (var claim in ctx.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = $"urn:facebook:{claim.Key}";
                        var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                        if (!ctx.Identity.HasClaim(claim.Key, claimValue))
                        {
                            ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Key, claimValue));
                        }
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Unlike some of the other answers, this combines the extra requested fields with what you get by default, and takes the `urn:facebook:` off the front of the claim so it matches the default claim naming scheme.

You don't need to add any additional `Scopes` or `Fields` (at least, not for first and last name).  Version 4.1 of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` already does this for you.  The [source code for the FacebookAuthenticationOptions is here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/FacebookAuthenticationOptions.cs).  Relevant bits:

```
    public FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        : base(Constants.DefaultAuthenticationType)
    {
        Caption = Constants.DefaultAuthenticationType;
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-facebook");
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
        Scope = new List<string>();
        BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        SendAppSecretProof = true;
        _fields = new HashSet<string>();
        CookieManager = new CookieManager();

        AuthorizationEndpoint = Constants.AuthorizationEndpoint;
        TokenEndpoint = Constants.TokenEndpoint;
        UserInformationEndpoint = Constants.UserInformationEndpoint;

        Scope.Add("public_profile");
        Scope.Add("email");
        Fields.Add("name");
        Fields.Add("email");
        Fields.Add("first_name");
        Fields.Add("last_name");
    }
```

If you are using IdentityServer 3 (like I am), then you will need to grab these claims on authentication in your custom `UserService` like so:

```
    public async override Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalAuthenticationContext ctx)
    {
        // first, lets see if we have enough data from this external provider
        // at a minimum, FirstName, LastName, and Email are required

        string email = null;
        string firstName = null;
        string lastName = null;

        var idp = ctx.ExternalIdentity.Provider;

        email = GetClaimValue(ctx, "email");

        if (idp == "google")
        {
            firstName = GetClaimValue(ctx, "given_name");
            lastName = GetClaimValue(ctx, "family_name");
        }
        else if (idp == "facebook")
        {
            firstName = GetClaimValue(ctx, "first_name");
            lastName = GetClaimValue(ctx, "last_name");
        }

        var missingClaims = "";
        if (email == null)
        {
            missingClaims = "email";
        }
        if (firstName == null)
        {
            if (missingClaims.Length > 0) { missingClaims += ", "; }
            missingClaims += "first name";
        }
        if (lastName == null)
        {
            if (missingClaims.Length > 0) { missingClaims += ", "; }
            missingClaims += "last name";
        }

        if (missingClaims.Length > 0)
        {
            var errorMessage = $"The external login provider didn't provide the minimum required user profile data.  Missing: {missingClaims}  " +
                "Verify that these fields are specified in your external login provider user profile and that you have allowed external apps (i.e. this one) access to them.  " +
                "Alternatively, you can try a different external login provider, or create a local acount right here.";
            ctx.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        var login = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserLoginInfo(ctx.ExternalIdentity.Provider, ctx.ExternalIdentity.ProviderId);
        var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(login);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // this user either does not exist or has not logged in with this identity provider
            // let's see if they already exist (by checking to see if there is a user account with this email address)

            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // there is no existing user with this email, therefore, a new user will be created
                user = new MotoTallyUser()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    UserName = email,
                    Email = email,
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lastName
                };
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, login);
            }
            else
            {
                // this user DOES exist (matched email provided by external login provider)
                // however, they have not logged in with this identity provider
                // therefore, update the user info with that reported by the external identity provider, and add the external login

                user.UserName = email;
                user.Email = email;
                user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                user.FirstName = firstName;
                user.LastName = lastName;
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, login);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // this user DOES exist (they already have an external login on record)
            // therefore, update the user info with that reported by the external identity provider (no need to add external login, its already there)

            user.UserName = email;
            user.Email = email;
            user.EmailConfirmed = true;
            user.FirstName = firstName;
            user.LastName = lastName;
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }

        ctx.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Id.ToString(), user.Email, null, ctx.ExternalIdentity.Provider);
        return;
    }

    private string GetClaimValue(ExternalAuthenticationContext ctx, string claimType)
    {
        if (ctx.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == claimType) != null)
        {
            return ctx.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == claimType).Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

For VB.NET developers this is the code In your Startup.Auth.vb

```
Dim fb = New FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        fb.Scope.Add("email")
        fb.AppId = "*"
        fb.AppSecret = "*"
        fb.Provider = New FacebookAuthenticationProvider() With
        {
            .OnAuthenticated = Async Function(context)
                                   context.Identity.AddClaim(New System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken))

                                   For Each claim In context.User
                                       Dim claimType = String.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key)
                                       Dim claimValue As String = claim.Value.ToString()
                                       If Not context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue) Then context.Identity.AddClaim(New System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"))
                                   Next
                               End Function
        }

        fb.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook has changed the way their Graph API returns value in upgrade 2.4**. Now you need to **explicitly specify** all the fields that you want to get back.

See this note from: [facebook for developers Upgrade Info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/):

> ***Graph API changes in version 2.4***
>
> *In the past, responses from Graph API calls returned a set of default fields. In order to reduce payload size and improve latency on mobile
>   networks we have reduced the number of default fields returned for
>   most Graph API calls. In v2.4 you will need to declaratively list the
>   response fields for your calls.*

**To get Email, FirstName and LastName from facebook:**

First, you need to install [Facebook SDK for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/) nuget package

Then, in your startup.Auth.cs, change the configuration of Facebook Authentication as follow:

```
     app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // put your AppId and AppSecret here. I am reading them from AppSettings 
            AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
            AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
            Scope = { "email" },
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        });

        // this is no longer needed
        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
        //   appSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"]);
```

Finally, in your AccountController, add the following code to
   ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
if (string.Equals(loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider, "facebook", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var access_token = identity.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken");
            var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            // you need to specify all the fields that you want to get back
            dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name"); 
            string email = myInfo.email;
            string firstName = myInfo.first_name;
            string lastName = myInfo.last_name;
        }
```

See [facebook API Guid](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) for more parameters that you can get back.

Answer (score -3):

Add firstname and last name in facebook option Scope

```
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "your app id",
                AppSecret = "your app secret",
            };

            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("first_name");
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("last_name");
            return facebookOptions;
```

Comment: first_name and last_name aren't valid scopes.