# ASP.NET MVC5 OWIN Facebook authentication suddenly not working

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

**Update 2017!**

The issue I had when I posted the original question has got nothing to do with the recent changes Facebook made when they forced everyone to version 2.3 of their API.  For a solution to that specific problem, see **sammy34's answer below**.  Version 2.3 of the /oauth/access_token endpoint now returns JSON instead of form-encoded values

**For historical reasons, here's my original question/issue:**

I've got an MVC5 Web application which is using the built-in support for authentication via Facebook and Google.  When we built this app a few months ago, we followed this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on and everything worked great.

Now, all of a sudden, the Facebook authentication has just stopped working alltogether.  The Google authentication still works great.

Description of the problem: We click the link to connect using Facebook, we are redirected to Facebook where we are prompted if we wan't to allow our Facebook app access to our profile.  When we click "OK" we are redirected back to our site, but instead of being logged in we simply end up at the login screen.

I've gone through this process in debug mode and I've got this ActionResult in my account controller as per the tutorial mentioned above:

```
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    ............
```

When stepping through the code and upon returning from Facebook, the loginInfo object is always NULL, which causes the user to be redirected back to the login.

In order to understand what is actually happening behind the scenes, I installed Fiddler and monitored the HTTP traffic.  What I disovered is that upon clicking "OK" at the Facebook permission dialog, Facebook redirects back to our application with this URL:

```
https://localhost/signin-facebook?code=<access-token>
```

This URL is not an actual file and probably handled by some controller/handler built into this OWIN framework I'm guessing.  Most likely, it is connecting back to Facebook using the given code to query information about the user which is trying to login.  Now, the problem is that instead of doing that, we are redirected to:

```
/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied
```

Which I'm sure is something Facebook is doing, that is, instead of giving us the user data, it's redirecting us back with this error message.

This causes the `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` to fail and always return NULL.

I'm completely out of ideas.  As far as we know, we did not change anything on our end.

I've tried creating a new Facebook app, I've tried following the tutorial again but I always have the same problem.

Any ideas welcome!

**Update!**

OK, this is driving me insane!  I've now manually gone through the steps required to perform the authentication and everything works great when I do that.  Why on earth is this not working when using the MVC5 Owin stuff?

This is what I did:

```
    // Step 1 - Pasted this into a browser, this returns a code
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=619359858118523&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=&state=u9R1m4iRI6Td4yACEgO99ETQw9NAos06bZWilJxJrXRn1rh4KEQhfuEVAq52UPnUif-lEHgayyWrsrdlW6t3ghLD8iFGX5S2iUBHotyTqCCQ9lx2Nl091pHPIw1N0JV23sc4wYfOs2YU5smyw9MGhcEuinvTAEql2QhBowR62FfU6PY4lA6m8pD3odI5MwBYOMor3eMLu2qnpEk0GekbtTVWgQnKnH6t1UcC6KcNXYY

I was redirected back to localhost (which I had shut down at this point to avoid being redirected immediately away).  The URL I was redirected to is this:

https://localhost/signin-facebook?code=<code-received-removed-for-obvious-reasons>

Now, I grabbed the code I got and used it in the URL below:

// Step 2 - opened this URL in a browser, and successfully retrieved an access token
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=619359858118523&redirect_uri=https://localhost/signin-facebook&client_secret=<client-secret>&code=<code-from-step-1>

// Step 3 - Now I'm able to query the facebook graph using the access token from step 2!

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<access-token-from-step-2>
```

No errors, everything works great!  Then why the hell is this not working when using the MVC5 Owin stuff?  There's obviously something wrong with the OWin implementation.

Comment: I'm working the same issue - started happening yesterday. I have a MVC5 app using the process described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928939/how-to-get-facebook-first-and-last-name-values-using-asp-net-mvc-5-and-owin. Works fine on my local dev environment, on azure platform am getting alternating errors of access_denied and FB error "Given URL is not allowed by the App configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings..."

Comment: Good I'm not the only one :-)  I'll be sure to let you know if I find a solution to this problem!

Comment: I had the same problem, putting http://example.com/signin-facebook as redirect url on facebook solved the issue

Comment: Following your URL testing approach I noticed that my app secret had changed! Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I've got a solution to the problem.

This is the code I had previously in my Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
var x = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
            //x.Scope.Add("email");
            x.AppId = "1442725269277224";
            x.AppSecret = "<secret>";
            x.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                {
                        //Get the access token from FB and store it in the database and
                    //use FacebookC# SDK to get more information about the user
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken",context.AccessToken));
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:name", context.Name));
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email));
                }
            };
            x.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(x);
```

Notice how the

```
x.Scope.Add("email")
```

line has been commented out, but still I'm query-ing for the e-mail later in the OnAuthenticated handler? Yup, that's right.  For some reason this worked flawlessly for a few weeks.

My solution was to simply uncomment the x.Scope.Add("email"); line to make sure that the scope=email variable was present in the initial request to Facebook.

Now everything works like it did!

I cannot understand why this worked before like it was.  The only explanation I can come up with is that Facebook changed something on their end.

Comment: this code has error, the code above lacks await operator

Comment: Thank you! Curiously I needed to make your change to get FB login to work from an Azure-hosted app (along with settings some values for `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` in my Facebook app settings) whereas from my dev environment everything worked fine without those amendments.

Comment: @HaukurHaf, is it possible that now this is failing again? No matter what I do, I can't get `context.Email` because it's allways null (login works but the context only has the id and user name)

Comment: I upgraded Owin to 3.0.1-RC1 and set `FacebookAuthenticationOptions { UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name"` in `Startup.Auth`; I was authorized and received email :) No extra `BackchannelHttpHandler` was needed.

Comment: @zed - This *almost* worked for me.  I had to add a check for `context.Email != null` and just ignore it if it was.

Comment: @HaukurHaf after the access token get stored in the DB. How do you access the access token from a Controller? For me the access token is automatically stored in the AspNetUserLogins table. Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 112):

**Update 22nd April 2017:** Version 3.1.0 of the Microsoft.Owin.* packages are now available. If you're having problems after Facebook's API changes from the 27th March 2017, try the updated NuGet packages first. In my case they solved the problem (working fine on our production systems).

**Original answer:**

In my case, I woke up on the 28th March 2017 to discover that our app's Facebook authentication had suddenly stopped working. We hadn't changed anything in the app code.

It turns out that Facebook did a "force upgrade" of their graph API from version 2.2 to 2.3 on 27th March 2017. One of the differences in these versions of the API seems to be that the Facebook endpoint `/oauth/access_token` responds no longer with a form-encoded content body, but with JSON instead.

Now, in the Owin middleware, we find the method `protected override FacebookAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync()`, which parses the body of the response as a form and subsequently uses the `access_token` from the parsed form. Needless to say, the parsed form is empty, so the `access_token` is also empty, causing an `access_denied` error further down the chain.

To fix this quickly, we created a wrapper class for the Facebook Oauth response

```
public class FacebookOauthResponse
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in OwinStart, we added a custom back-channel handler...

```
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "hidden",
            AppSecret = "hidden",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler()
        });
```

...where the handler is defined as:

```
public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("access_token"))
            return result;

        // For the access token we need to now deal with the fact that the response is now in JSON format, not form values. Owin looks for form values.
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var facebookOauthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookOauthResponse>(content);

        var outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        outgoingQueryString.Add(nameof(facebookOauthResponse.access_token), facebookOauthResponse.access_token);
        outgoingQueryString.Add(nameof(facebookOauthResponse.expires_in), facebookOauthResponse.expires_in + string.Empty);
        outgoingQueryString.Add(nameof(facebookOauthResponse.token_type), facebookOauthResponse.token_type);
        var postdata = outgoingQueryString.ToString();

        var modifiedResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(postdata)
        };

        return modifiedResult;
    }
}
```

Basically, the handler simply creates a new HttpResponseMessage containing the equivalent form-encoded information from the Facebook JSON response. Note that this code uses the popular Json.Net package.

With this custom handler, the problems seem to be resolved (although we're yet to deploy to prod :)).

Hope that saves somebody else waking up today with similar problems!

Also, if anybody has a cleaner solution to this, I'd love to know!

Comment: Any sauce on the "force upgrade"?

Comment: Same problem here, thanks for your post.
Azure Mobile Services are affected too. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/397f6952-57bf-4c28-b383-6bba08d28f9a/facebook-login-failures-with-app-service-authentication-authorization?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3 for further details about facebook changes. Also RFC specification mentioned https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.1

Comment: This has been fixed in 3.1.0-RC1 https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38

Comment: Unable to get login information from ExternalLoginCallback action method. Trying HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null.

Comment: It feels like having a cloud above my head if you think that my ever first try to create a facebook login was actually on March 28th...

Comment: Yesterday I read someone telling us to upgrade *Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook* to `3.1.0-RC1`, unfortunately I got some assembly manifest errors after doing that, maybe this wasn't the right package to upgrade. So I *undid* this upgrade and got sammy34's code, and it worked nicely.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!.. This really works. I was not able to get it done with 3.1.0-RC1 even. But this solution works like a charm!

Comment: A stable version of 3.1.0 has been released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/

Comment: To get the Users email & Name you may Need to Manual specify the Facebook endpoint:

FBopt.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=email,name"

Comment: I updated the related Owin Packages to 3.1 and applied the above code, but the problem persist. What is weird that the facebook authentication is working on my local environment but once deployed on a remote server (with a  ".com" valid certificate) it is not working. Any idea why? is there some environment configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 27):

Noticed this problem yesterday. Facebook does not support Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook version 3.0.1 anymore. For me it worked to install version 3.1.0. To update to 3.1.0, run the command `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` in Package Manager Console: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook

Comment: Still not working for me, I updated to the latest version 3.1.0-rc1 and made sure all DLLs got updated, https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38

Comment: Unable to get login information from ExternalLoginCallback action method. Trying HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null.

Comment: A stable version of 3.1.0 has been released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/


This thread is also helpful for troubleshooting:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38

Comment: Thanks very much you save my time after 6 hours of investigations!

Comment: You are a rockstar. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue with the Google Authentication. The following worked for me: [Changes to Google OAuth 2.0 and updates in Google middleware for 3.0.0 RC release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. To summarize for others go to console.developer.google.com  and select your application go to APIs & Auth > APIs > and ENABLE "Google+ API". If you provisioned the application before Sept 1, 2014 is will be disabled and that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The last Facebook upgrade was on 2015-02-09 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth/)

The latest version of the API at that point was version 2.2. Version 2.2 expired on the 25th of March 2017, which is coincidentally when the problem started. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

I'm guessing Facebook probably automatically upgraded the API and now the MS OAUTH library is unable to parse the new response.

tldr: The Microsoft WebPages OAuth library is outdated (for FB at least) and you'll probably have to find another solution

Comment: You should switch to [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.1.0-RC1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/3.1.0-rc1). I also used DonNetOpenAuth library until Facebook force to switch us to graph API v2.3 at least. So we upgrade our solution from MVC 4 to MVC 5 and switched to OWIN and it's implementation. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well, but it wasn't caused by the scope setting. Took me a long time to figure that out, but what finally clued me in was by setting a custom logger by setting the following in `OwinStartup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`.

```
app.SetLoggerFactory(new LoggerFactory()); 
// Note: LoggerFactory is my own custom ILoggerFactory
```

This outputted the following:

> 2014-05-31 21:14:48,508 [8] ERROR
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware
>   [(null)] - 0x00000000 - Authentication failed
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending 
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not
>   be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com'    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult 
>   ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler.d__0.MoveNext()

Based on the above call stack I found that my Azure VM was unable to resolve graph.facebook.com. All I had to do to fix that was to run "ipconfig /registerdns" and I was all fixed...

Comment: Why don't you insert your LoggerFactry to help others?

Comment: @MarcoAlves - My logger implementation is very custom & wouldn't work for anyone else. I just did a little digging & there's a DiagnosticsLoggerFactory (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.logging.diagnosticsloggerfactory.aspx) that probably would work for you.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was this and it is solved now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894789/how-to-renew-the-access-token-using-the-refresh-token/24972426#24972426

Comment: I had the same problem with a slightly different root cause: The X509 certificates used to sign the Facebook SSL certificate was not installed on the server so when I navigated to https://www.facebook.com/ in a browser I got a certificate error. Fixing this fixed the signin problem.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions didn't work for me. In the end, it seemed to be related to the Session. By "waking up" the session in the previous call, it would no longer return null from the GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        Session["WAKEUP"] = "NOW!";
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

Like the OP, I had the 3rd party auth working fine for a long time then suddenly it stopped. I beleive it was due to the changes made in my code when I set up the Session to use Redis Cache on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on solution for three days. And I've just found it on github(https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38#issuecomment-290400987)

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "xxxxx",
    AppSecret = "xxxxx",
};

// Set requested scope
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");

// Set requested fields
facebookOptions.Fields.Add("email");
facebookOptions.Fields.Add("first_name");
facebookOptions.Fields.Add("last_name");

facebookOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            // Attach the access token if you need it later on for calls on behalf of the user
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));

            foreach (var claim in context.User)
            {
                //var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                var claimType = string.Format("{0}", claim.Key);
                string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();

                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
       }
};

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

And to get values

```
var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

if (info != null)
{
    var firstName = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "first_name").Value;
    var lastName = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "last_name").Value;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen such a great answer in my lifetime (: Really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check you get an outside internet connection from your application. If not, fix your outside internet connection. My problem was I was using an EC2 AWS instance that suddenly stopped connecting to the internet. It took me a while to realize that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me insane. All was working until I deployed to my staging environment. I was using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook version 3.0.1 from Nuget. Updated it to the prelease version 3.1.0 from Nuget and I no longer got the access denied error...

Comment: this did the trick (such issues best be solved by the framework) - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/3.1.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

Even though i did everything what **sammy34** said, it did not work for me. I was at the same point with **HaukurHaf**: When i make apirequest manually on browser it works perfect, but if i use my mvc app, `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` always returns *null*.

So i changed some rows on **sammy34**'s codes like on this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148543/7776015

Replaced:

```
if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
{
request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
}
var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
{
return result;
}
```

Instead of:

```
var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("access_token"))
return result;
```

And added this row into my `FacebookAuthenticationOptions`:

```
UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture"
```

and now it works.(fields and  that parameters optional)

Note: I did not update `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook`