# Facebook OAuth stopped working suddenly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, model-view-controller, oauth, owin

I noticed yesterday that my Facebook login for my website has stopped working.

This has been working great for the last 2 months, as far as I am aware I have not changed anything. I have tried everything I can on links such as: -  as well as many more...

[ASP.NET MVC5 OWIN Facebook authentication suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working)

I have noticed that the Stack Overflow Facebook auth has also stopped working.

Has anyone else noticed this and found any solution?  It's worth noting I am using azure app services to host.  But this issue is also found when I am using localhost.

My current setup looks like this...

in Startup.Auth.cs

```
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

In the following method, `loginInfo` is `null` every time.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

I also added a session "WAKEUP" from a different post suggestion, fb auth failed once before and this fixed the issue this time, but it has come back.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    Session["WAKEUP"] = "NOW!";

    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: Sorry I have added a little more detail now... is this enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As RockSheep explained. Facebook dropped the support vor API v2.2. You need to update your OWIN nuget packages.

You can find [the issue on github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38) (from the Katanaproject).

Ensure to activate **pre releases** in your nuget manager, than you are able to update the nuget packages to version *v3.1.0-rc1*. But beware: After the update, you need to test your login carefully (maybe you also have other authentication providers like Microsoft or Google, you should test them as well).

**Technical**

The Api changed the version number to v2.8 and the return value from the API is now in JSON-Format and no longer escaped in the URI. The 'old' OWIN packages can not handle this changes.

> [Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of
>   https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you
>   exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of
>   being URL encoded. The new format of this response is {"access_token":
>   {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this
>   update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

[Here you can find the code-changes](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/commit/b32efb31da8834a6877a354c7d49ef6190873f0a) on GitHub for further informations and better understanding.

Comment: You are a life saver... this has fixed my issue thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people started having trouble after yesterday. This is due to Facebook dropping support for v2.2 of their API. For some reason their system still redirects auth calls that don't use a version number to the 2.2 API. A quickfix is to ensure that the API version gets sent with the API call.

Starting at v2.3 Facebook also started returning JSON objects. So make sure to change that in the code as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, apologies if this is a daft question, but how do I send the version number with the API call?

Comment: I've never worked with C# so I can't really help you there, but a lot of my projects started failing due to this issue.

Comment: @user3284707 To send version number set endpoint options this way:          `facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "**",
                AppSecret = "**",
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,email,name,picture.height(180)",
                AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth"
            };
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);  `                    In your startup.auth.cs file found in appstart

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,   found solution here  [Fix facebook oauth 2017](http://mindly.org/facebook-login-oauth-fix-2017-getexternallogininfoasync-null-access_denied/)

Basically, you need to extend HttpClientHandler and decode JSON response instead of body

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for those who are using scribe java.

```
 public Token extract(String response)
  {
    Preconditions.checkEmptyString(response, "Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from an empty string");
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    return new Token(obj.get("access_token").toString(), EMPTY_SECRET, response);
  }
```

Comment: in the TokenExtractor20Impl.java file

Comment: Awesome, you saved me!  Yeah, I had to implement my our version of TokenExtractor20Impl, but basically replace the extraction piece with your code!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class and set the extractor to JSON.

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi20;
import org.scribe.extractors.AccessTokenExtractor;
import org.scribe.extractors.JsonTokenExtractor;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthConfig;

public class FaceFmApi extends DefaultApi20 {

    @Override
    public String getAccessTokenEndpoint()
    {
        return "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
    }

    @Override
    public AccessTokenExtractor getAccessTokenExtractor()
    {
        return new JsonTokenExtractor();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizationUrl(OAuthConfig config) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and inject your newly created class as below. Then `getAccessToken()` will work as expected.

```
public OAuthService getService() {
    return new ServiceBuilder().provider(FaceFmApi.class)
        .apiKey(config.getApiKey()).apiSecret(config.getApiSecret())
        .callback(config.getCallback()).build();
}
```