# New #access_denied with Facebook Login (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm facing a strange problem with Facebook Login on my website. It's something completely new, Facebook login has always worked correctly and it's still working on my Android and iOS App.

I have a Link in the website like:

```
 http://myURL/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http://myURL/Home/Register?
```

Obviously in developer.facebook.com I have everything set up like, in OAUTH ADDRESS I have:

```
 http://myURL
 http://myURL/Home/Register
 http://myURL/Home/Register?
```

And I have also my localhost (that worked correctly since a couple of days ago)

My App requires this access:

```
       var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "[Hidden For Security Reason]",
            AppSecret = "[Hidden For Security Reason]"
        };
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("user_friends");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

My graph api version is v2.6

When I click the link, I get to facebook, I put my credentials in and it returns me to myURL#access_denied.

Does anybody have any clue?

Comment: You switched from Graph API 2.2?

Comment: Not sure, havent' change a thing. Simply stopped working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook did a "force upgrade" of their graph API from version 2.2 to 2.3 yesterday.
But the issue and the fix are better explained here : [ASP.NET MVC5 OWIN Facebook authentication suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working/43063384#43063384)

Comment: Yes, it is the change from String to JSON. See here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog (Changes from v2.2 to v2.3 / [Oauth Access Token] Format)