# URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings?

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-web-app-service, facebook-apps

I followed the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication to set up Facebook login.

In the https://developers.facebook.com/apps, the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" has the following URI

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback
```

However, it still gets the error?

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

---

*Update:*
Added both `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook` and `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback`. And now the website got error of

`A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier, it can be configured by setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.`.

On the line of `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in `d:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Account\_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtm`

---

*Update:*
Added the followign line in global.asax and the error above is gone.

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

However, it just shows the following message box with url of `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#_=_`.

```
You have successfully signed in
-> RETURN TO THE WEBSITE
```

Clicking the link will return to the login screen. https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ (which doesn't need to be authorized) stead of https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/event. Typing https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/event will show the login page again. (redirected to https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fevent)

Answer (score 2):

As this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-mobile%2ftoc.json) about Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service:

> App Service Authentication / Authorization is a feature that provides a way for your application to sign in users so that **you don't have to change code on the app backend**. It provides an easy way to protect your application and work with per-user data.

You could browser at `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook` for logon.

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

You could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network package to check your facebook logon processing as follows:

[image]

**Note:** Make sure the above `redirect_uri` has been added to **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**. **HTTP** or **HTTPS** could be a possible cause.

Additionally, if you use the Middleware `UseFacebookAuthentication` for authenticating users using Facebook, I assumed that you need to add `http(s)://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook` to **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** or you could try to use the following code:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "{your-app-id}",
    AppSecret = "{your-app-secret}",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/.auth/login/facebook/callback")
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#creating-the-app-in-facebook-and-connecting-the-app-to-the-project) about handling Facebook authentication by using OWIN in ASP.NET MVC5, I found that I could not retrieve the logged facebook user info and the `returnUrl` is not working. After some trials, I found that Facebook did a force upgrade of the graph API from v2.2 to v2.3 as follows:

Facebook Graph API, [Changes from v2.2 to v2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog):

> [Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you exchange a code for **an access_token now return valid JSON instead of being URL encoded**. The new format of this response is {"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

You need to upgrade [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/) to 3.1.0, or you need to implement the [BackchannelHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.facebook.facebookauthenticationoptions.backchannelhttphandler(v=vs.113).aspx) mentioned in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working/43063384#43063384).

Comment: I tried to use fiddler and my network packages seem different. It post `POST https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLogin?ReturnUrl=%2Fevent HTTP/1.1`, then tunnel to `CONNECT 2-edge-chat.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.0`, then `GET https://2-edge-chat.facebook.com/pull?channel=p_100000343225510&seq=0&partition=-2&clientid=.....`?

Comment: Another time I got `GET https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=365322087148601&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=&state=3hmmvp23P8PQvmH78BtKA....`.

Comment: Cleared and added `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook` in the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs". The error is gone. However, it doesn't redirect to the `/event` page.

Comment: Then I added the code `CallbackPath = new PathString("/.auth/login/facebook/callback")` (`new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()`). And now the error of `URL Blocked` reappear.

Comment: As you described, you are using `App Service Authentication/Authorization`, at this point, you need to add  `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback` to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" and you don't have to add any Middleware ( e.g. `app.UseFacebookAuthentication`) for authenticating users login in your backend. If you use `app.UseFacebookAuthentication` to handle facebook authentication by your web app itself, you need to add the default `CallbackPath` (`https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook`) of  `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".

Comment: Have you both enable "App Service Authentication/Authorization" on Azure Portal and use `app.UseFacebookAuthentication` in Startup.Auth.cs ? Also, how did you set **Action to take when request is not authenticated** under the "Setting > Authentication / Authorization" of your web app?

Comment: Yes, the following code exists in the app `app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
               appId: "....",
               appSecret: "....");` and `App Service Authentication` is enabled. "Action to take when request is not authenticated" is set to "Allow Anonymous requests (no action)". Right now the issue is it stay in the login screen.

Comment: Have you checked the update in my reply? I may encounter the same issue after logged, but the page is not redirect to the right page. This is due to facebook graph api has a force upgrade,  you could try to upgrade this package **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** to 3.1.0.

Comment: The version of the file in my project is v4.0.30319. I posted a new question for most updated status -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508984/asp-net-on-azure-cannot-login-facebook-location-account-externallogincallback

Comment: You could refer to this similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working/43063384#43063384) and implement the `BackchannelHttpHandler`.

Comment: Since this issue is more about URL Blocked when using Facebook login, I have provided approach for you to troubleshoot and locate this issue. The remaining question is about `access_denied` which is another question and you have opened another issue. I would keep researching your new issue. If my efforts could help you to solve the current issue, kindly mark it as an acceptable answer.