# Asp.net on Azure cannot login facebook? Location: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied

Tags: asp.net, facebook, azure, azure-web-app-service, facebook-apps

I followed the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication to set up Facebook login.

In the https://developers.facebook.com/apps, the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" has the following URIs

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook 
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback
```

However, the site cannot login - the login page just stays. Type an Url https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/event will always redirect to https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fevent.

The following is the Net traffic captured by fiddler. It seems the request is denied when `GET https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook?code=....` (Response: `Location: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied`)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=365322087148601&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=&state=E4J6p7jhJVr2YT1SYqxzHKoUJ1u04QtfVu8UUtgoRzK8xPfXvHnWSFJE5TGKOn9AoqVQkvGZHzakiNoTme2bQBm27n1riQTPTCLNrIoybUxhV-wXpyUDYrkXVawTs0JMtTOW1UK2gv_1YJ_A9EkbvPSZMXN-NW56vF2lq8d-9iPG7fTv41CGV3-0bVV2dAEW86gyO70VLVdQ5X2byye_XFS3XNkhtVJEbfXio_RMRvE HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.5,zh-Hans;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: www.facebook.com
Cookie: fr=0RObsAfMX8N2oDE0P.AWUijY5j4ajj3MWCbj2nVPEp4Go.BY9tIg.oW.Fj2.0.0.BY-AuR.AWU2VfKJ; datr=INL2WBkTq1-aa6V7IMJUUMMw; dats=1; sb=JNL2WJ2XCIs_K6QaFHEcvbTM; c_user=100000343225510; xs=251%3A-D7EtOmwXRbYlQ%3A2%3A1492570660%3A12220; pl=n; lu=ggNZWbJ4ElBZhc5tOVdylWWA; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1492652361EuserFA21B00343225510A2EstateFDutF1492652361094CEchFDp_5f1B00343225510F195CC


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook?code=AQC2JMYoeLmJAHtkTiHMTEckID_cdoJZ0eFkuffNCSh-XDzgZWCm-cJbDyIMJaLEa-mLApgU54MoppjOS0CH3b6jWCN-VDXsqq7z-6TALE35OdralWJRFSZQs7k-_4qBk4Vl8HmeW0INO5V4NL9nVU1tlDSqF6PoAN4Dee5DvvJyr_w_-ZE2ZG_dfY5zcq2-G9dNcqVGDs3YWzDQfP3VmWu-4kFZ3YUC8ENfFoUZPw8uvOBGPEgr_92aK8cQJnLXd1k98jCKb-sIzQHB9XCfUFW1QrMeww4EqvTvINl0Pu0O8l--M-zATFoMnQW6et8RRhBarAbmYSVMGCkClEFUDPe9Mcn8-qsFr1WBv4kqtLrnSA&state=E4J6p7jhJVr2YT1SYqxzHKoUJ1u04QtfVu8UUtgoRzK8xPfXvHnWSFJE5TGKOn9AoqVQkvGZHzakiNoTme2bQBm27n1riQTPTCLNrIoybUxhV-wXpyUDYrkXVawTs0JMtTOW1UK2gv_1YJ_A9EkbvPSZMXN-NW56vF2lq8d-9iPG7fTv41CGV3-0bVV2dAEW86gyO70VLVdQ5X2byye_XFS3XNkhtVJEbfXio_RMRvE#_=_
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
facebook-api-version: v2.8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
public-key-pins-report-only: max-age=500; pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18="; pin-sha256="r/mIkG3eEpVdm+u/ko/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E="; pin-sha256="q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ="; report-uri="http://reports.fb.com/hpkp/"
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Type: text/html
X-FB-Debug: BOC8IkjZ4va1buTLdHl+OgLKK4ymT3oyi4SALf8bnAQx2MDqHkCvmTGsTMngZazRs0dFZ6SSHYSi0U6mcbaQNw==
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 01:42:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0



------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook?code=AQC2JMYoeLmJAHtkTiHMTEckID_cdoJZ0eFkuffNCSh-XDzgZWCm-cJbDyIMJaLEa-mLApgU54MoppjOS0CH3b6jWCN-VDXsqq7z-6TALE35OdralWJRFSZQs7k-_4qBk4Vl8HmeW0INO5V4NL9nVU1tlDSqF6PoAN4Dee5DvvJyr_w_-ZE2ZG_dfY5zcq2-G9dNcqVGDs3YWzDQfP3VmWu-4kFZ3YUC8ENfFoUZPw8uvOBGPEgr_92aK8cQJnLXd1k98jCKb-sIzQHB9XCfUFW1QrMeww4EqvTvINl0Pu0O8l--M-zATFoMnQW6et8RRhBarAbmYSVMGCkClEFUDPe9Mcn8-qsFr1WBv4kqtLrnSA&state=E4J6p7jhJVr2YT1SYqxzHKoUJ1u04QtfVu8UUtgoRzK8xPfXvHnWSFJE5TGKOn9AoqVQkvGZHzakiNoTme2bQBm27n1riQTPTCLNrIoybUxhV-wXpyUDYrkXVawTs0JMtTOW1UK2gv_1YJ_A9EkbvPSZMXN-NW56vF2lq8d-9iPG7fTv41CGV3-0bVV2dAEW86gyO70VLVdQ5X2byye_XFS3XNkhtVJEbfXio_RMRvE HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.5,zh-Hans;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: myapp.azurewebsites.net
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=49xMNw5ePC60qAaVBtxq5TAbkgpGbkcPyb5OcWmO0CYNstOX7vUQJAST80cvsFM16l0USNgUCr9b5RCn3cnXXlsGhpz33rme4A_HRw1QFNY1; ARRAffinity=f86b281b78014bea7ff499f4d5d3d562aafe8f1cf9e24d7ef4dc3d48d94a9c32; .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=hcA83RJONYyZTzuT0I3kTRJM6DTK9OUsmmrQKV_mAkU


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 0
Location: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie: .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 01:42:20 GMT
```

**Startup.Auth.cs:**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: ".....",
           appSecret: ".....");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**
After updated Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, facebook login prompted me to register a new user. However, it still redirect to login page? The following is the http traffic.

```
POST https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLogin?ReturnUrl=%2Fevent HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fevent
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.5,zh-Hans;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: myapp.azurewebsites.net
Content-Length: 196
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=49xMNw5ePC60qAaVBtxq5TAbkgpGbkcPyb5OcWmO0CYNstOX7vUQJAST80cvsFM16l0USNgUCr9b5RCn3cnXXlsGhpz33rme4A_HRw1QFNY1; ARRAffinity=f86b281b78014bea7ff499f4d5d3d562aafe8f1cf9e24d7ef4dc3d48d94a9c32; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=VkuppVPkn0nPbkYf5aSoSKrYsJVWusdEU4TKvf_bPajqbd7gMexZ4muf43ZnpSOwt9P6L60Lc_7VBWZu8Q41eIN2qw3vmhdcAC3gypOhFrQ57T-ymAyJX838uGjsjE3zw_RlVr1kLbyomB5xFVz5azv3nMCm4DDGadGQTSrPdEOQ54GVTQiDJJ9wi4vAd7Cc96ssc4J4x9HrWRIwdZiorubCJpyd1SUeDd6MkZTQgdxGPR42NBwr1CH7DDymU2fJSMw7Dw6Qi5IDNYwFL32J0rsc_5ji_VxvbUBhJZDFGwOxsQ5cFzm0k-XuqJB5zH1aS-6WvQ97sAbu4kQOt0BCZc3EhBAy9c5gmRmq1HyB-NiDwxhbpcS1e57M_9yNmdh8l9phHpnrthk2JNxzyom1Ni-nTbkbZsFdQ2SwuzuPaKS_R1IvXG57q7GM3QEzzTkjsZmuEPCaP5IvFfjISH8kVFBzCnoCoYkvjTKNsfG05VY


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=365322087148601&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=&state=wq_uw7UGAFosxcCkR_Oa7P9gyBQeE4DbW92-YZN0tgOFzlOTLeFxDsaVVmH9SsEY6rkZb3zU4ZRBjcp3nQf-b4V-lbXSihHBIzol77_SiBOX7b-GI8iDtPfp9VFuXbhXZWn--GY5xhjOLXnMCu1idq-Y53qMLm_mhX_oOFuOqgyLmqz35Cf3ardNKUT9tdXUyrLOkOCndQ3R2KSWx_FJ0qzptM6J0IyCvk-JwFkEKvjAh3-mgopTgnIKP-LHBL2Z
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie: .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=dfeXeK1QG0fHz_lgWH9nLhCT4Zw0USACEAyA0oAZzZ8; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 03:49:27 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=365322087148601&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=&state=wq_uw7UGAFosxcCkR_Oa7P9gyBQeE4DbW92-YZN0tgOFzlOTLeFxDsaVVmH9SsEY6rkZb3zU4ZRBjcp3nQf-b4V-lbXSihHBIzol77_SiBOX7b-GI8iDtPfp9VFuXbhXZWn--GY5xhjOLXnMCu1idq-Y53qMLm_mhX_oOFuOqgyLmqz35Cf3ardNKUT9tdXUyrLOkOCndQ3R2KSWx_FJ0qzptM6J0IyCvk-JwFkEKvjAh3-mgopTgnIKP-LHBL2Z HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fevent
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.5,zh-Hans;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: www.facebook.com
Cookie: fr=0RObsAfMX8N2oDE0P.AWUijY5j4ajj3MWCbj2nVPEp4Go.BY9tIg.oW.Fj2.0.0.BY-AuR.AWU2VfKJ; datr=INL2WBkTq1-aa6V7IMJUUMMw; dats=1; sb=JNL2WJ2XCIs_K6QaFHEcvbTM; c_user=100000343225510; xs=251%3A-D7EtOmwXRbYlQ%3A2%3A1492570660%3A12220; pl=n; lu=ggNZWbJ4ElBZhc5tOVdylWWA; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1492652361EuserFA21B00343225510A2EstateFDutF1492652361094CEchFDp_5f1B00343225510F195CC


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook?code=AQCGF2xmMpxqeJOvGi0ngPWLVPqxKZL19gdGPeZdYjQ0k6S-Ta_WS0VxOBxR7wcz70IzHkeC-jQw8KAy7NNP-9m0_atTD6OJYjFZpbnAyixkg7-2r6_B5MR3_nzSBVqc8orXBeBy4KbcG0pgcW6AYGOX1inJaXixCbvypqK5JSgj8RTjbnTd8OmMMzVhC6QBpuViHEcnwOKMx3YgaOEyV9GXwr39EBY-WvcDlu1b__L7vSD9y1VA5jGfAX7jRTmXOOOPrgU-KVOnvqrAUj4RgfpS2YqEFa59t9k00emP2L2FRq94HHBzZshI3dwN0kFH6nVu1y8VKuGqgIDJqbkiXPj88kgbC612wocVpuST4Y0q2g&state=wq_uw7UGAFosxcCkR_Oa7P9gyBQeE4DbW92-YZN0tgOFzlOTLeFxDsaVVmH9SsEY6rkZb3zU4ZRBjcp3nQf-b4V-lbXSihHBIzol77_SiBOX7b-GI8iDtPfp9VFuXbhXZWn--GY5xhjOLXnMCu1idq-Y53qMLm_mhX_oOFuOqgyLmqz35Cf3ardNKUT9tdXUyrLOkOCndQ3R2KSWx_FJ0qzptM6J0IyCvk-JwFkEKvjAh3-mgopTgnIKP-LHBL2Z#_=_
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
facebook-api-version: v2.8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
public-key-pins-report-only: max-age=500; pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18="; pin-sha256="r/mIkG3eEpVdm+u/ko/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E="; pin-sha256="q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ="; report-uri="http://reports.fb.com/hpkp/"
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Type: text/html
X-FB-Debug: ABkQtw3vY1sccWewy5h4luP2SmaMQXgOUnv2HfxKkMGR7VFV+3Jq7+HOsVnGAESUXqI7RT+raZ/CrCLo3U1JbQ==
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 03:49:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

There is a `X-Frame-Options: DENY` for the request of `GET https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=....`

Comment: I have created a sample project for you to isolate this issue, you could refer to my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could encounter the same issue, after some searches I found that the facebook graph api did some changes. Here is the detailed info, you could refer to it:

Facebook Graph API has a force upgrade: [Changes from v2.2 to v2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

> [Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/**access_token returned when you exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of being URL encoded**. The new format of this response is {"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

Since the `access_token` returned with the JSON instead of the URL encoded, [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/) prior to 3.1.0 could not handle this change. You need to upgrade **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** to 3.1.0 version, or you need to implement the [FacebookAuthenticationOptions.BackchannelHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.facebook.facebookauthenticationoptions.backchannelhttphandler(v=vs.113).aspx) for a workaround to handle this change, for more details, you could refer to this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working/43063384#43063384).

**UPDATE**

As I known, [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) indicates whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`, I assumed that this header has no relation with your issue. Since your network packages are from your client, you could not see the processing when you use `authorization_code` to exchange the `access_token` from facebook. I recommended that you could run your web app on your local side and capture the packages as follows:

[image]

I have checked both update **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** to 3.1.0 and implement [FacebookAuthenticationOptions.BackchannelHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.facebook.facebookauthenticationoptions.backchannelhttphandler(v=vs.113).aspx) by following this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working/43063384#43063384), both could work on my side and azure. In summary, you could get the `authorization_code` but failed to extract the `access_token`, I assumed that you need to clear/rebuild your project and make sure your project could work on your local side, then redeploy your project to web app (if you deploy the website via VS publish wizard, you could choose the "Remove additional files at destination" under **Settings > File Publish Options** or you could use [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to empty your web content).

**UPDATE2**

I have created a code sample [AspDotNet-WebApplication-FacebookAuth](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-WebApplication-FacebookAuth) with my facekbook app, you could try to run on your local side and make sure you could retrieve the `access_token` and get the logged user info as follows:

[image]

Comment: It works now. I thought I was using v4.0.30319 but it turns out it's "Runtime Version". My old version is 2.0

Comment: Still not working. I've appended the issue at the end of the question.

Comment: Are you mean you also get the access_denied? I have updated my reply, you could refer to it and check with your project.