# ASP.NET web api login with facebook not working when deploying to Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, azure

I am developing an ASP.net web app which uses Facebook authentication. 
I'm using the MVC ASP.NET App template. When integrating Facebook Login it's working perfectly fine when running on https://localhost but when I deploy the same app to Azure using App Services it's timeing out while being re-directed back to the App from Facebook. 
Is there anything special what needs to be configured on the Azure side ?

It's very similar to [Asp.net on Azure cannot login facebook? Location: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508984/asp-net-on-azure-cannot-login-facebook-location-account-externallogincallback) and all help provided does not help.

Comment: Can you please share your network trace?

Comment: _“it's timeing out while being re-directed back to the App from Facebook”_ - that would be the part where your app has to make a connection to Facebook for the first time, making an API call to exchange the code for a token. So I would start by checking whether your app is allowed to make outgoing connections, or gets blocked by firewall etc.

Comment: ok so ... tracked it down to a missing SQL Server for the MVC template...tries to connect to a local database. Unbelieveable why this is not being documented in MSFT docs...

Comment: @PeterJaeger Can you tell me how you managed to change the connection on the database. I am having same issue.