# MVC 5.2 Facebook C# SDK 6.8.0 - Type or Namespace "FB" could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to follow this tutorial to access more user information when they log in using Facebook.
[Get more information from Social providers used in the VS 2013 project templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx)

Ultimately I would like to be able to get data such as the user's firstName, lastName, Zip, etc. when a user logs in using Facebook and store that in the AspNetUsers table when they register. I will try this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928939/how-to-get-facebook-first-and-last-name-values-using-asp-net-mvc-5-and-owin)

For now I would just like to get this tutorial working but it is slightly different from my MVC 5.2.2 project. I am getting a 'type or namespace name "FB" could not be found. How can I fix this error?

Also, the ExternalLoginCallback is different, would I add the "`await StoreFacebookAuthToken(user);`" above `var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

I opened the Package Manager Console and it displayed a message which said that I was missing assemblies and it gave me the option to Restore the assemblies.

Than I received an error, "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
So I went to Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... and I just updated everything then it worked.